# rails console hangs in production environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have postgresql setup for my production schema in database.yml. I was able to successfully run RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate but when I do do RAILS_ENV=production rails console, it hangs. Never gives me the console prompt.

I've also tried bundle exec rails console production but didn't help.

Output:

Connecting to database specified by database.yml
...hangs after this.

Running rails 3.2.11 on ruby 2.1.2. I have rbenv and rbenv-gemsets installed.

Comment: it should be `rails console production`

Comment: I had some issues with hanging console too, and stopping spring helped. That was not a production environment though.

Answer (score 0):

To run the rails console in the production environment you need to pass the name of the environment after the command. The actual command is as follows.

```
rails console production
```

If that doesn't work, try restarting your PostgreSQL server and try again. It could be that you have crossed the number of possible connections with the PostgreSQL database.

Comment: Tried that too didn't work. I restarted postgre and the server itself.